# Alternative to LEAD in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had a problem that I had to solve. I did development in SQL Server 2019 but where I am going to put it in SQL Server 2008, and I used a function that helped me a lot but I can't use it because it is only available from SQL Server 2012 upwards:

- **LEAD:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The case (example) is this:

```
SELECT 
a.ID AS Id,
b.ID AS Id2,
a.date1 AS date1
DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD(b.date, 1) OVER(ORDER BY b.Id, b.date)) AS date2
FROM Table 1 AS a
LEFT JOIN Table 2 AS b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

The idea is that the date2 is 1 day before the date1 of the record that comes in the following line.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to replace this? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Did SQL Server 2008 reach end of life already?

Comment: The usual way of simulating `LAG`/`LEAD`  in 2008 was to use a row_number and outer join on row_number  = row_number +1.

Comment: Yes, 3 years ago, @TheImpaler , and the next version (2012) reached it on Monday.

Comment: @tg_dev3 check this out https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lag-and-lead-for-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @tg_dev3 In the future, and if you can afford to, you might want to avoid jobs that involve very out-of-date software.

Comment: @devesh thanks a million for your help and the link you provided! That the answer! I already resolve the problem and now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
with init_Data as(
   SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY b.Id, b.date) as rn,
          a.ID AS Id,
          b.ID AS Id2,
          a.date1 AS date1,
          b.date AS date2
     FROM Table 1 AS a
     LEFT JOIN Table 2 AS b ON a.Id = b.Id
    
)
select d1.Id,
       d1.Id2,
       d1.date1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, coalesce(d2.date2, 1)) as date2
from init_Data d1
join init_Data d2 on d1.rn = d2.rn+1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's not doing exactly what I I want. The answer I was looking for is in this link: https://sqlscope.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/lag-and-lead-for-sql-server-2008/